# How to return 2 decimal points for BigDecimal in JSON response from Scala/Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, bigdecimal

Here is my case class.

```
case class DecimalWrapper(money: BigDecimal, type: String)

object DecimalWrapper {
    implicit val decimalWrapperMarshaller = Json.format[DecimalWrapper]
}
```

When trying to do Json.toJson(DecimalWrapper(2, "whole sale")) it returns

```
{
   "money": 2
   "type": "whole sale"
}
```

what I would like it to return is **2.00** for the money field.

I couldn't find out a way to specify a custom serialiser to always return 2 decimal points with rounding HALF_UP.

Anyone please kindly help?

Regards
Tin

Comment: `type` is a reserved word in Scala so your example won't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might seem more involved but it'd be a good idea to define a separate `writes` for `BigDecimal` if you intend to reuse that writes logic throughout your application.  One thing to note is you have to use it explicitly, you can't declare it implicit as there is already an implicit writes defined for `BigDecimal`.

```
val decimalWrites = new Writes[BigDecimal]{
  def writes(o: BigDecimal): JsValue = JsString(o.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString())
 }

implicit val decimalWrapperWrites: Writes[DecimalWrapper] = (
  (JsPath \ "money").write[BigDecimal](decimalWrites) and
  (JsPath \ "type").write[String]
)(unlift(DecimalWrapper.unapply))
```

Comment: Thanks Josphpconley. The code you provided works, however, it returns a type of String e.g "2.00" instead of 2.00. In Java, I could write a custom serializer for Jackson, and register it globally with Spring. Could it be done the same way in Scala/Play Framework?

Answer (score -1):

You can write your Writes manually.
Something like:

```
implicit val myWrites= new Writes[DecimalWrapper] {
  def writes(a: DecimalWrapper): JsValue = Json.obj(
    "money" -> a.money.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString(),
    "type" -> a.`type`
  )}
```